# fix content to the top of the page Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a page with a list view and some information at the top of the list. I would like to fix this information so when the user scrolls through the list the information is still visible.

here is what i have [tried](http://jsfiddle.net/kPLK4/1/)

As you can see the `div`with `id: #fixed-info` is fixed but is showing up at the bottom of the page. i need it to be displayed between the header(also fixed) and the list view.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kPLK4/19/

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Note: I gave the fixed div an id of 'fixed' and a data-position of 'fixed top', then I also added some simple styling to make it look a little more normal. Change the red background to match that of the list and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing position:static; ? I read that was the fix for people wanting to use position:fixed; on an element

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following css style to the info div:

```
 top:20px;
 z-index:10;
```

where the value of your top css will be the height of your header.